# How to know which @Input changes in ngOnChanges?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2.

Right now I have two @input `aa` and `bb`. I want to do:

1. If `aa` changes, do something.
2. If `bb` changes, do other thing.

How to know which @Input changes in `ngOnChanges`? Thanks

```
  @Input() aa;
  @Input() bb;

  ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange }) {
    // if aa changes, do something
    // if bb changes, do other thing
  }
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Might be able to do it this way

```
ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange }) {
  if( changes['aa'] && changes['aa'].previousValue != changes['aa'].currentValue ) {
    // aa prop changed
  }
  if( changes['bb'] && changes['bb'].previousValue != changes['bb'].currentValue ) {
    // bb prop changed
  }
}
```

I'm surprised that the unchanged properties are defined, though.  From the cookbook, I would expect that only changed properties would be defined.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-on-changes

If that is too verbose, you could also try using the setter approach:

```
_aa: string;
_bb: string;

@Input() set aa(value: string) {
  this._aa = value;
  // do something on 'aa' change
}

@Input() set bb(value: string) {
  this._bb = value;
  // do something on 'bb' change
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-setter

Comment: thanks, but I think it is wrong. Because I tried, if only `aa` changes, `if(changes['bb']) { // here still runs }`

Comment: Oh, my question `aa` and `bb` are `string`. My app they are `Object`, so I feel how to compare is really depends on the type of  `aa` and `bb`. Thanks!!

Comment: Makes sense.  Maybe the setter approach would fit your need better?

Comment: For the second method, the code is even not running. `@Input() set  a(value: string) {// here not running}`. I think it is still wrong

Comment: I made a plunk to demonstrate this behavior:  http://plnkr.co/edit/dZO3atoWWiES6jIWIyzY?p=preview

Comment: You could do `changes: SimpleChanges` instead of `changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange }`

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of  `!=`

Comment: @harunurhan You can also type it as `Record<keyof this, SimpleChange>` and you will get autocompletion

Comment: I had not seen the setter pattern before. It's so much more effective at catching specific changes compared to ngOnChanges!  Thanks for this suggestion.