# What is the correct way to handle this scenario on 'ngChanges'

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-input

I am supplying a downloadable data to child through `@input` value.    when user click on download link it's downloading the file without any issue.

But whenever there is a change going on and observed by `ngOnchanges` - triggers the download again and i am getting downloaded a unknown file. so, how to fix it or how can i make only it download the file on user click alone?

on user click i am triggering download event.

```
@Input() cpDownloadedFile: any;


initDownloadFile(fileData) {

    this.fileDownloaded.emit(fileData.Id);

}

ngOnChanges() {

      change1,

      change 2

       //other changes goes here

      if (this.cpDownloadedFile && changes.cpDownloadedFile) {
            const element = document.createElement('a');
            element.href = URL.createObjectURL(this.cpDownloadedFile);
            element.download = this.fileName.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/\_(?=[^_]*$).*(?=\.)/g, '');
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            element.click();
        }

}
```

Comment: Whats the reason for handling download in ngOnChanges rather than a button click

Comment: any specific reason to downloading the file from `ngOnChanges()`...?

Comment: can you show your `onClick` code?

Comment: @all, I am download a file from ngrx/store. so on click I am `emit` the event. later looking the changes to get file download. let me add my click event

Comment: I assume the *listener* of `emit` has the same code as inside the `if` block mentioned above? Can you post the complete code of the component or the `click` listener? This appears to have a simple solution with all these details.

Comment: @AakashMore - I am not get you.. can you describe what you look exactly

Answer (score 0):

By what I understand from the given information, Even if the `ngOnChanges` is causing a file to download on change of other attributes, It should trigger the download of the *last downloaded file*. Are you sure the `cpDownloadedFile` is not changing elsewhere?

Try replacing the `if` condition to with the following,

```js
if (this.cpDownloadedFile && changes.cpDownloadedFile &&
    changes.cpDownloadedFile.currentValue !== changes.cpDownloadedFile.previousValue )
    { /* download code */ }
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404107/how-to-know-which-input-changes-in-ngonchanges)

Comment: But it will not work. because as a first time after user trigger the event I am getting correct file get downloaded. after on wards getting some file without extension which is created the name by ash key. so each time the file would be new!!

Comment: I didn't understand you. Can you please elaborate what happens the first time?